# We have two teams across Asia and Europe, and plan to show a movie. Is there a way to connect them users to a common platform?

Tags: windows

We want to see if there is a way where the users can login to a common platform and view the movie at the same time.

Is there any open source platform where they can join a movie screening online? Similar to how gotomeetings are done.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube and Twitch are the most popular platforms for both Live Broadcast and not live broadcasts.

I'll recommend live streaming the video and making it private on twitch to prevent any copyright case.

For YouTube streaming you have to have some conditions fulfilled.

[YOUTUBE TERMS FOR GOING LIVE](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en-GB)